# wp_query return empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have custom post type 'book' and I also make taxonomy name best-book which. I want to filter taxonomy term but it doesn't work. I try to put echo and print_r to find where is my problem and I found that my $loop var return empty array. I also use this style in other pages and never have problem but I can't find why this happen? and how can I have fix it.
here is the photo which show it return empty array 
[image]
here is my code

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type'=>'book'); 
    loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    print_r($loop);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $post=the_post();

    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'best-book', array("fields" => "all"));

    foreach($term_list as $term_single) 
}

?>
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this line**

```
loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**To**

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**The full code**

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type'=>'book'); 
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    print_r($loop);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $loop->the_post();

    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'best-book', array("fields" => "all"));   
    foreach($term_list as $term_single){
         ------Your Code Goes Here------ 
   }  
?>
```

Comment: good to see you again :D. no in my real code it is $loop I change it before

Comment: Hello again, xD `loop = new WP_Query( $args );` this doesn't make any sense at all. First define parameter to `$loop` and see the result.

Comment: thx, and mind me ask you another question? I have problem with filtering taxonomy items.

Comment: oh, what's wrong with taxonomy ? where you got stuck ?

Comment: because it is different topic can u join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122095/taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
    $args = array( 'post_type'=>'book'); 
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    print_r($loop);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $post=the_post();
        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'best-book', array("fields" => "all"));            
    endwhile;
```